# Split Excel table to tables based on Column value and copy them to MS Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy

Given Excel Table with following data:

| Group ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 25 |
| 2 | George | 31 |
| 3 | Adam | 45 |
| 1 | Alex | 55 |
| 2 | Andre | 31 |
| 3 | Lucas | 26 |

I wanna have such VBA script, which will split this table to subtables for each group and then it will export all these tables to MS Word document. Currently I have a VBA script, which is able to split the subtables to separated sheets, but I don't know, how to just export the subtables to MS Word.

So the Word Document will contain 3 tables:

| Group ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 25 |
| 1 | Alex | 55 |

| Group ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | George | 31 |
| 2 | Andre | 31 |

| Group ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Adam | 45 |
| 3 | Lucas | 26 |

This is my current code:

```
Sub SplitByColumn()

Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
Dim xTRg As Range
Dim xVRg As Range
Dim xWSTRg As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set xTRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the header rows:", "Kutools for Excel", "", Type:=8)
If TypeName(xTRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the column you want to split data based on:", "Kutools for Excel", "", Type:=8)
If TypeName(xVRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
vcol = xVRg.Column
Set ws = xTRg.Worksheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = xTRg.AddressLocal
titlerow = xTRg.Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('xTRgWs_Sheet!A1')") Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
Else
    Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet").Delete
    Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
End If
Set xWSTRg = Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet")
xTRg.Copy
xWSTRg.Paste Destination:=xWSTRg.Range("A1")
ws.Activate
For i = (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter Field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    xWSTRg.Range(title).Copy
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Paste Destination:=Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    ws.Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count))
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
xWSTRg.Delete
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any VBA (or splitting to sub-tables in Excel) for this - it can all be done from Word using DATABASE fields (one for each Group ID). This has the added advantage that the Word tables will update to reflect changes in the Excel data with no intervention on your part.

For example, assuming the Word document and Excel workbook are stored in the same folder, the DATABASE fields could be coded as:

```
{DATABASE \d "{FILENAME \p}/../myfile.xlsx" \s "SELECT [Group ID], [Name], [Age] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Group ID] = {SEQ ID} ORDER BY [Name] " \l "9" \b "47" \h}
```

You could simply copy/paste the completed field however many times you need to accommodate all the IDs. Alternatively, if you create another worksheet with just a 'Group ID' column containing all the IDs you want to output, you could use a similar field as part of a mailmerge connected to the worksheet containing just the 'Group ID' column:

```
{DATABASE \d "{FILENAME \p}/../myfile.xlsx" \s "SELECT [Group ID], [Name], [Age] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Group ID] = {MERGEFIELD Group_ID} ORDER BY [Name] " \l "9" \b "47" \h}
```

The \l "9" \b "47" \h switches tell Word how to format the output. If you use Word's Insert|Quick Parts|Field>Database>Insert Database>Get Data (connect to the workbook/worksheet)>Table AutoFormat, Word will show the various formatting options that are available. Those formats are stored in the numbers following the \l and \b switches, plus the presence or absence of the \h switch.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

For a non-mailmerge demonstration, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21847-mail-merge-into-different-coloumns.html#post67097

For a mailmerge demonstration, see: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1273421-merge-excel-list-into-word-receipt.html#post5110813

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I tried implement it, but getting error, when trying to generate multiple tables for each ID. So basically this query doesn't work:
```
DATABASE  \d "C:\\myfile.xlsx" \s "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [ID] = {MERGEFIELD ID}" 
```
But this works, unfortunatelly generating only one big table:
```
DATABASE  \d "C:\\myfile.xlsx" \s "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" 
```
Any idea, what could be wrong,please?

Comment: Well, for starters, since you're not using a mailmerge, you wouldn't use a test that evaluates `{MERGEFIELD ID}`. Moreover, since your field name is `Group ID`, you wouldn't use `[ID]` for the test. And, unless your Excel workbook is actually located in the root folder of your C: drive, you wouldn't use `"C:\\myfile.xlsx"`. Look closely at posts 6 & 8 in the linked thread.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the ID I used instead of Group ID was because I tried some debugging, because I was not sure, how the spaces in columns work. So this is the proper field code: DATABASE  \d "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\myfile.xlsx" \s "SELECT [Group ID], [Name], [Age] FROM [Sheet1$]" \l "9" \b "47" \h  \* MERGEFORMAT 
The problem, which I have, is basically spliting the main table into multiple tables based on [Group ID]. Of course I can do multiple fields with WHERE, how its done in your thread. But this is demo table, in reality, I have around 800 Group IDs and I cant do 800 Where's condition.

Comment: I like your answer a lot, it contains a lot of interesting information, there is I guess last part, which I still didn't get and I was not able to make it working.
I'm definitely going the way of using dedicated Excel sheet - Sheet2 (same workbook). But when I'm using in query - {MERGEFIELD Group_ID} , firstly how Word is able to realize it will take the Group_ID from Sheet2? Dont I have to specify the Sheet2 somewhere? Btw. When my column is "Group ID", the "Group_ID" you wrote is typo or there is some implicit conversion replacing space with underscore?

Comment: The mailmerge would point to what you refer to as 'Sheet 2', solely for the purpose of getting the Group IDs. You do this at the time you set up the mailmerge and tell Word which worksheet to work with. The DATABASE field continues to refer to '[Sheet1$]', employing the results of the Group ID returned by {MERGEFIELD Group_ID} to determine which group to output. Although the Excel column Heading you're using says 'Group ID', with a space, the mergefield (but not the rest of the DATABASE field) needs to refer to it as {MERGEFIELD Group_ID}, with an underscore instead of a space.