# Split single table into multiple tables based on value in column 4

Tags: vba, split, ms-word

This is very similar to this question, except all my work in only in WORD.

[Split Excel table to tables based on Column value and copy them to MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258442/split-excel-table-to-tables-based-on-column-value-and-copy-them-to-ms-word)

I want to split a word table similarly and paste 3 tables in the same document.

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: The code is too long to post here.
Here is a link with the code: https://jpst.it/2Xi2y

The issue is - if there are only a few categories - e.g. there is a row marked C, but no row marked S - then the wrong tables are deleted.

Comment: Perhaps I could bookmark the table that is going to be split up, so that it is reliably deleted later?